# Apache Drill JDBC Plugin Doesnt Recognize Columns

Tags: jdbc, plugins, schema, apache-drill

I'm attempting to query a proprietary RDBMS using Apache Drill.  I've created the plugin as a JDBC data source and put my JDBC jar in the jars/3rdparty directory, and I'm able to successfully run a query such as `SELECT * FROM mytable`.

However, if I use a column name in the query such as `SELECT mycol FROM mytable`, Drill returns the following error: `Error: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 8 to line 1, column 9: Column 'mycol' not found in any table`.  Moreover, I've noticed that my schema is entirely missing if I run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`, so I have a hunch that Drill is unable to retrieve my database schema from the JDBC driver.

I'm wondering what method of the JDBC driver may be implemented incorrectly that's causing this problem.  The JDBC driver has been used with other 3rd party software such as Spark with no issue.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform a query on your table you need to prefix the name of your table with the name you gave your storage plugin. For example if you named your storage plugin **rdbms** your query should look like this:

`SELECT * FROM rdbms.mytable`

Your additional query `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` likely failed for the same reason. Try `SELECT * FROM rdbms.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`. And don't forget to replace **rdbms** with the name you gave your storage plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should query on drill like `select * from dfs.<storagePlugin>.tableName`

Can you check once.?